# sql query for top 10 records

Tags: mysql, sql

Can anyone help me for a simple SQL query?

This is the scenario: i need to find the runners who took part to more competitions. Competitions have been in different cities and different specialities. The following table shows better what i mean:

Runner: John White

```
        -----------------------------------------
        |  NY  |  Rome |  Madrid |  Los Angeles |
 ------------------------------------------------
 | 100m |  x   |       |   x     |              |
 ------------------------------------------------
 | 200m |      |  x    |         |      x       |
 ------------------------------------------------
 | 400m |      |       |         |              |
 ------------------------------------------------
```

In few words i have a database with the following fields: name, city, spec and i need to find the runner who filled more slots, the runner who participated to more different competitions.
In the "spec" field data are 100m or 200m or 300m if he took part respectively to each speciality
In the example the result is John White -> 4

So, how can i make a query to list the 1st ten runners who participated to the major number of competitions? I need a table showing the runner name and the number of competitions he took part.

Thanks in advance for your help. If you need more infos just ask.

Bye, Mat

UPDATE: In few words i'd like to know the top 10 list of names that have the maximum number of different combinations of city-specs fields. This one i think is the best logical way to explain my answer.

Here is an example of the database:

```
name     city      spec
-----------------------
john     NY         100m
john     Rome       200m
john     Madrid     100m
john     Los Ang    200m
mike     Rome       200m
mike     Rome       100m
```

The "top 10 list" i'm looking for will be the following:

```
john   4
mike   2
```

I hope that now it is all ok. Bye!

Comment: Honestly, I have no idea what this is asking :(

Comment: Please clearify the stucture of tables. "i have a database with the following fields: name, city, spec" not understand

Comment: I edited the question,tell me if now is better.

Answer (score 11):

Perhaps you are looking for something like this:

```
select name, count(distinct city) as attended
  from competitions
 group by name
 order by 2 desc
 limit 10;
```

This query returns a competitor and number of events he participated in, excluding duplicates (100 and 200 meters at the same event). If you want to count all appearances remove *distinct* keyword, and in case you want to show versatility list replace *city* with *distinct speciality*. Query works by counting all rows that belong to the same **name**, ordering by that count descendingly and limiting output to ten rows.

UPDATE: I suppose that OP needs a list of top 10 competitors by appearance. So, each record for competitor counts as one:

```
select name, count(name) as attended
  from competitions
 group by name
 order by 2 desc
 limit 10;
```

Will give 4 for Mr. White, and 12 for anyone who attended all 4 competitions in all 3 disciplines.

Comment: Hi nikola, please read the question again, i edited it andnow is more clear, i hope. I mistaked somethingbefore, sorry. Furthermore give a look also to my answers to others here. Maybe this may help you more to understand my question. Sorry for my mistakes. I'm waiting for your help. Bye

Comment: @Mattew, please check the UPDATE section of my answer.

Comment: in few words i'd like to know the top 10 list of names that have the maximum number of different combinations of city-specs fields. This one i think is the best logical way to explain my answer.

Comment: Then my answer answers your question :-)

Comment: well it seems to work good but if i have two identical city-specs combinations associated to john, your query counts 2 times the same event :)

Comment: In that case put count (distinct city, spec)

Comment: `if i have two identical city-specs combinations associated to john` --> I wonder how `john` managed to run twice in the same competition :)

Comment: @MostyMostacho: I guess one can run as 1st and 4th in 4x400m competition :)

Answer (score 0):

Wouldn't either the City or the Event be irrelevant? Couldn't you just take a count of its association in a single city, seeing as how it looks like every event association has a city and vise versa? I'm assuming there's another join table or two somewhere as well. But I'd select the count of how many times the person appears in that join.

```
SELECT COUNT(*)
FROM city_runner
WHERE runnerid = ? #The runner's id? You gave so little for me to work with...
```

Then use your application language to determine whose is greatest...

Comment: Hu kyle, thanks for your answer. I try to exlain me better. Firstly i edited the question so that you can read there. Furthermore i can say you that the database has three fields: name, city, spec As yu can imagine in the "name" field there are names of a lot of runners. In the "city" field there are all the cities of the competitions and in the "spec" field there are only three different data: "100m","200m" and "400m" depending to the different competition.So let's suppose that the different cities have been 4, in this case the best runner took part to a maximum of 12 competitions.. and so on

Answer (score 0):

That really very much depends on how your data is structured. I can imagine you have a table with

`city|name|spec`

In that case, your solution is trivial:

```
SELECT TOP 10 name, total_races
FROM (
  SELECT COUNT(*) as total_races, name
  FROM thattable
  GROUP BY name
) as t1
ORDER BY total_races DESC
```

If your data is stored differently, the query will be different, obviously

Edit: It's really the same thing with your table. I edited the query to have `name` instead of `runner`, but it's still the same answer

Comment: Hi Martijin, i edited the question and now i hope it is better. Anyway the database has 3 fieds: name, city, spec. So, for each runner i can have different cities.Tthe field "spec" has only three different values: "100m", "200m" and "400m". In few words i need to count the total competitions he took part considering all the cities and all the specialities he runned. thx in advance.

Comment: if I understands you correctly, then still the above query, though I doubt I do

Comment: No, in few words i'd like to know the top 10 list of names that have the maximum number of different combinations of city-specs fields.

Answer (score 0):

This will work To find the **nth maximum number**

```
    SELECT TOP  nth_largest_no * FROM Products Order by price desc
```

For Example

```
  SELECT TOP  10 * FROM Products Order by price desc;
```